# Detect safari advanced setting: "never use font sizes smaller than..." from javascript?

Tags: javascript, safari

Safari (mac) has a setting under safari -> preferences -> advanced that disabled the use of fonts smaller than a given point size.

I'm writing a PDF application using PDF.js which causes the fonts to be rendered huge and overlap when this setting is enabled.

I'm trying to find out if there is a way from javascript to detect if this setting is enabled or not before loading the PDF, and then instead load a message explaining to the user what they need to do to properly view the PDF.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a DOM node with a `font-size: 1px, line-height: 1.0` and measure its height.  If it's `> 1px`, then your font size is capped.

http://codepen.io/nevir/full/trwEb

Comment: Yeah i ended up just figuring this out on my own and forgot to post back with an update, but thank you for the correct response!

Comment: measuring height does not work, as only the computedStyle changes. `$.css('font-size')` does.